# Wait until same event has happened for a timespan using Rx

Tags: c#, winforms, events, delay, system.reactive

Using Reactive.NET, how can I wait until the same event has happened for n seconds before performing an action?

The following sample (C#, WinForms) is doing what I want, but I want a delay (let say 1 second) before the expanding happens:

```
var autoExpand = Observable.FromEventPattern<DragEventArgs>(tree, "DragOver");

autoExpand
    .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
    .Distinct(dragEvent => tree.GetNodeFromCoordinates(dragEvent.EventArgs.X, dragEvent.EventArgs.Y))
    .Subscribe(dragEvent => {
            TreeNode node = tree.GetNodeFromCoordinates(dragEvent.EventArgs.X, dragEvent.EventArgs.Y);

            if (node != null) node.Expand();
        });
```

Comment: Why not using Task and Task<T> and the ContinueWith() functions? It is native to .net

Comment: I'm yet to use Rx, but you probably want [Delay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff708297%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) after the `Distinct`.

Comment: @David I'm to lazy to write code to handle the delay I'm searching for, maintaining background threads etc.

Comment: @Zurb, I don't quite follow. What do you mean?

Comment: @David How can I solve the problem using Task? I was using Rx so I did not need to deal with background processes, what node was last selected, the time that has elapsed, Invoke on Controls etc.

Comment: I don't see apparent obstacles of using Task, did you have a read on Task<T> msdn reference?

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor By the way, delay was not the solution: it was just delaying (and blocking) and running the code 1 second later; even when the user already has dragged-over to another node.

Comment: @Zurb OK, thanks for the information, that was just a guess. Maybe it'll be useful to me when I finally get to use Rx :)

Comment: @David when dealing with streams of events, Rx is the preferable tool for the job. `Task` and `Task<T>` are useful to represent aynschronous operations but they are not relevant to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `Throttle`:

```
var autoExpand = Observable.FromEventPattern<DragEventArgs>(tree, "DragOver");

autoExpand
    .Select(dragEvent => tree.GetNodeFromCoordinates(dragEvent.EventArgs.X, dragEvent.EventArgs.Y))
    .DistinctUntilChanged()
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
    .Subscribe(node => {
            if (node != null) node.Expand();
        });
```

Note:

- To avoid making `tree.GetNodeFromCoordinates()` twice, I have used it with the `Select` operator to bring it through to the subscription
- Handily, we can use `DistinctUntilChanged` to block repeated node selection events if the node is the same
- I have moved the `ObserveOn` operator to after the `Throttle` call to avoid blocking the thread - general guidelines for `ObserveOn` suggest that you should leave it as the last operator before your subscription. If you do need to use `SynchronizationContext.Current` for `tree.GetNodeFromCoordinates()` then you might need to switch schedulers a few times to avoid cross-threading exceptions.

Comment: Yes! Works! Thanks for the optimizations!